# ElasticSearch - Return only matched token not whole string when quering

Tags: java, elasticsearch, indexing, lucene, string-matching

How can I get list of matching tokens only not whole string when querying index.
Say, we have to query a field which contains list of values like -

```
'Sunsilk shampoo conditioner'
'Dove Soap'
'Bread Bun Biscuit'
'Sunscreen cream'
```

When I query `s`, it should return only-

```
'Sunsilk'
'shampoo'
'Soap'
'Sunscreen'
```

Comment: You could use highlighting to get some more help from ES about which token matched and then parse the JSON response and get the highlighted words out, but to make ES return just that list I'm not sure it's possible. For highlighting: `{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "fields": ["whatever"],
      "query": "*s*"
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": { "whatever": {} }
  }
}`

Comment: Thanks Andrei. It worked. Now i need to get distinct highlight. I am getting <em>Shampoo</em> multiple times

Comment: Still outside ES, as an auxiliary step.

Comment: Now only way to make these distinct is by using java api? Does ES got any option to do it?

Comment: Java or whatever client you are using. I'm not sure ES does have this option, because you need just the words out of a field that can be an entire phrase or sentence. ES will match the field and will show you (with highlighting) which words (tokens) from that field matched. I don't think it can take out only the tokens that matched and, even more, getting a distinct out of them.